# Как организовать базу с переменным количеством полей?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Приведу пример. 
Есть таблица пользователей сайта, каждый пользователь имеет логин и пароль.
Есть таблица покупателей на сайте, они же являются пользователями, но кроме всех данных пользователя имеют, например, email и баланс.
Есть продавцы - это пользователи, но с полями логин и пароль и телефон.
Есть директор - у него все поля пользователя и еще 10 других.
Есть гл.бухгалтер - у него все поля пользователя, и 8 полей таких же как у директора.
И так далее...

Так вот, я создал таблицу пользователей. Потом сделал таблицу покупатели, добавил туда id пользователя и уникальные для покупателя поля. 
Так же с продавцом.
Еще создал таблицу другие, вставил туда id пользователя и все поля всех оставшихся чуваков.

С одной стороны все вроде логично. Но мне не нравиться. Может быть есть какое-то более красивое решение?

Кто нибудь встречался с такой проблемкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте по отдельной таблице для каждого типа пользователей и перенесите туда все поля кроме общих для всех типов (например, логина и пароля). Затем свяжите все специализированные таблицы с основной через внешний ключ с отношением 1:1.

Тогда у вас получится следующий набор таблиц:

- *пользователи*: id, логин, пароль;
- *покупатели*: id_пользователя, email, баланс;
- *продавцы*: id_пользователя, телефон;
- ...

Чтобы работать с основной и вспомогательной таблицами как с единым целым, не нарушая при этом нормализацию («более красивое решение»), вам также потребуется создать объединяющее представление. К слову, оно является обновляемым, то есть поддерживает обновление и удаление записей.

На SQL это будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
-- Таблица всех пользователей
create table users(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    login varchar(15) not null,
    password_hash binary(20) not null,
    password_salt binary(10) not null,

    primary key(id)
);

-- Дополнительная таблица пользователей-покупателей
create table buyers(
    user_id int not null,
    email text not null,
    balance int not null,

    index user_id_key(user_id),
    foreign key buyers_users(user_id)
        references users(id)
        on delete cascade
        on update cascade
);

-- Представление, объединяющее все данные о покупателе
create view buyers_users_view as
    select id, login, password_hash, password_salt, email, balance
    from buyers
    left join users on buyers.user_id = users.id;
```

Тот же код на SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/582b8be.

Comment: Я так и думал изначально. Проблема была в реализации моделей, которые бы работали с двумя таблицами одним объектом. Но это уже другой вопрос

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко, добавил в ответ информацию о представлениях (view).